# How can a few small Python scripts be run periodically with Docker?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I currently have a handful of small Python scripts on my laptop that are set to run every 1-15 minutes, depending on the script in question. They perform various tasks for me like checking for new data on a certain API, manipulating it, and then posting it to another service, etc.

I have a NAS/personal server (unRAID) and was thinking about moving the scripts to there via Docker, but since I'm relatively new to Docker I wasn't sure about the best approach.

Would it be correct to take something like the [Phusion Baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) which includes Cron, package my scripts and crontab as dependencies to the image, and write the Dockerfile to initialize all of this? Or would it be a more canonical approach to modify the scripts so that they are threaded with recursive timers and just run each script individually in it's own [official Python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)?

Answer (score 0):

No dude just install python on the docker container/image, move your scripts and run them as normal.
You may have to expose some port or add firewall exception but your container can be as native linux environment.